# Objectbox Flutter - iOS app crashes on startup

Tags: objectbox

I set up an Objectbox db for my flutter app following the instructions here - https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started - and it worked a treat. Fast, easy, and no issues at all when deployed to to various Android devices. Different story on iOS: app crashes immediately, with the following error:

```
(lldb) dyld[10127]: Library not loaded: @rpath/ObjectBox.framework/ObjectBox
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/31AC8A15-C7D8-4116-A4F2-7DA3892609DD/Runner.app/Runner
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/ObjectBox.framework/ObjectBox' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/ObjectBox.framework/ObjectBox' (no such file),
'/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/31AC8A15-C7D8-4116-A4F2-7DA3892609DD/Runner.app/Frameworks/ObjectBox.framework/ObjectBox' 
(mach-o file (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/31AC8A15-C7D8-4116-A4F2-7DA3892609DD/Runner.app/Frameworks/ObjectBox.framework/ObjectBox), 
but incompatible platform (have 'iOS-sim', need 'iOS')),
```

As described in the getting-started doc I've set the architecture in XCode to arm64, and that shows up in my flutter project in ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj under buildSettings as:

```
ARCHS = arm64;
```

Why does the iOS build of my app crash?

Comment: The message indicates the packaged ObjectBox library is for the simulator, not a real device. How do you build and run the app? Using `flutter run` (or any of the options from https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive)?

Comment: Progress. In Xcode, I defined architectures like this:

    $(ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT)

(note syntax). That broke deployment *to the simulator*, so I added exclude of arm64 for 'Any iOS Simulator SDK' in XCode too. I also updated my podfile like this:

target.build_configurations.each do |config|
  config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
end

The app deploys to the simulator just fine. Haven't tried it on a real device yet.